# How to extract text from image in pdf file?

Tags: apache-tika

I am using `tika` in my python application to extract text from documents. Everything is working fine, but it is not extracted from an image that is in pdf file. `Tika` is extracting text from pdf as well as images, but not from the pdf that contain images. I am bit confused. Is there any way to do that? Do I need to convert the PDF file into image?

Answer (score 0):

The site https://pdf2text.online/ does exactly what you are looking for. It extracts editable text from PDFs and performs OCR on the images which are found in the PDF. Like that you get the complete information as editable text.